# Can I install app to provisioned devices without physically connecting to dev computer

Tags: iphone, distribution, device

I have successfully provisioned 5 development devices to be used in testing during the development phase. This is working fine because I initially did it by physically plugging each iPhone into my MAC and installing the software.

However my testers are remote and so it is a pain to have to meet with them to install new versions for testing.

Is there a way for me to distribute the new test versions to them remotely? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an Ad Hoc build using your distribution certificate (not the development certificate).

Add the test device UDID's into the Devices section of the provisioning portal in the dev center. Then create a Distribution provisioning profile, selecting 'Ad Hoc' as the type, and check all the devices required.

Download this profile and add it to XCode.

From there, I suggest you follow this guide: http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

Once you have the .ipa file, you can email this to your testers, who can install it using iTunes on their own mac or PC.

Comment: This is correct, a good refrence for this if you are a registered developer is http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/distribution.action

Comment: Whilst the dev center does have some useful material, some of the adhoc documentation appears out of date, and references the way it was done prior to xcode 4.

Comment: You can also use services that allow you to do over the air distribution which is much simpler for end users (load url in safari -> click download link -> confirm install). If you want to role your own there is an excellent tutorial here http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/

Answer (score 0):

you must check this link to install app without itunes

http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

and you also prefer TESTFLIGHT for your clients for testing purpose

https://testflightapp.com/